# PHP GD compressing png but not compressing Jpeg

Tags: php, png, jpeg, gd, image-compression

The following works very well for png files, but for jpeg/jpg the compression doesn't work.

```
function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
    return $destination;
}
```

How do I get it to compress jpeg?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What happens?

Comment: jpgs are always compressed. but if you set the quality too high, the file size can be artificially increased for zero gain in actual quality.

Comment: @adrian my 700KB jpeg file is still 700KB afterwards.

Comment: If you're compressing it at the same quality it was originally, then it will end up roughly the same size.

Comment: I haven't already compressed the image with php and I set it quality to 80.

Answer (score 0):

In order to manipulate JPEG files with GD, your version of PHP needs to be compiled with libjpeg support built in. You can check this on `phpinfo`. Look for the following two:

- JPEG Support  enabled
- libJPEG Version   6b *(or different)*

If you don't have those, ask your host.

Another issue that might come from this is that your mime type for jpeg images might come up as unknown. Double-check the library version - if it is there, comment back and I'll see if I can find a problem in your code by more than library introspection.

Comment: His issue isn't that he doesn't have libjpeg, OP stated he can create JPEGs from PNGs just fine.

Comment: Cool. I have both JPEG Support enabled and libJPEG Version 6b.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with PHP.

Do:

yum install gd gd-devel